# Crankarms trek slash 9 2014

Tags: crankset

I need to change my crankarms, because mine are broken.  But I don't know which one to buy.  I have a trek slash 9 2014.
Thnx

Comment: You need to know whats compatible with your bottom bracket. As for which one to buy, we don't do product rec here.

Comment: What you mostly need to do is to match the fittings on the ends of the crankshaft.  These are either a tapered square or one of two basic splined designs, or, on very old bikes, a round shaft with a flat on it (known as a "cottered" crank).  For a 2014 Trek it's probably one of the splined standards.

Comment: Please add some more info, like a clear photograph of the cranks and of the bottom bracket.   You'll probably need to buy a tool to remove the cranks, and possibly one for the pedals too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try Googling Trek Slash 9 2014 to find out what it has:  I did, and I found this:

http://archive.trekbikes.com/gb/en/2014/Trek/slash_9#/uk/en/2014/Trek/slash_9/details

It says:

Crank

> SRAM X01, 32T

And it also tells you it has a pressfit bottom bracket.

So I suggest you buy a SRAM X01 crank.  I don't know where you live, but you can buy that online, e.g.

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/sram-x01-11-speed-bb30-carbon-crank-arms/?lang=en&curr=GBP&dest=1&sku=5360581639&kpid=5360581639&utm_source=google&utm_term&utm_campaign=UK_PLA_Components&utm_medium=base&utm_content=mkwid%7csNcPz8iyR_dc%7cpcrid%7c67090789142%7cpkw%7c%7cpmt%7c%7cprd%7c5360581639uk

(also found by Googling BTW).